# comment system with redis - use lists?

Tags: redis

I am making a *really* simple comment system on my site, using lists;

Posting is done trough LPUSH with the id of the commented item. The retrieval is done trough LRANGE, then looping trough the resulting array.

I was wondering if this is the best way to handle comments? Is it a good idea on a performance level?

Also how would I go for moderation? It doesn't seem to be a way to remove a particular item from the list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to delete comments based on index instead of using [LREM](http://redis.io/commands/lrem) (which seeks and deletes based on list item value), you can use sets and hashes.

Keep a simple set for each post, with the id of comments on that post:

```
SADD Comments:post:1 1
SADD Comments:post:1 2
```

(this will mark post ID 1 having comments ID 1 and 2)

Then for each comment set a hash key:

```
HSET Comments:1 1 "This will be a comment for post 1"
HSET Comments:1 2 "A second comment for the same post"
```

Then you can query hash `Comments:1` for all comments on e.g. post ID 1:

```
HGETALL Comments:1
```

And deletion of a single comment can be done like:

```
SREM Comments:post:1 1
HDEL Comments:1 1
```

(Here deleting the first comment).

Comment: do you think that using sets and hashes is also better on a performance point of view?

Comment: For deletion, `O(N)` in SREM takes `O(1)` (deleting 1 item for instance) and in LREM, `N` is the length of the list.